# Посоветуйте как правильно сделать разметку для диалога

Tags: java, android, xml, dialogfragment, android-dialog

Я хочу поменять дизайн диалога, конкретно кнопок.

Сейчас он выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я хочу сделать кнопки легче чтоб было как то так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас в своем диалоге я использую свою XML разметку и в ней просто кнопки.

Насколько я понимаю мне нужно использовать обычные `TextView` и поставить между ними разделители, которые я думаю нужно сделать в виде обычных `View` просто задать им высоту `1dp` и `backgraung` нужного цвета...

Но я не уверен, что это самое ровное решение это во первых, а во вторых как задать длину этих разделителей(полосок между кнопками). Если поставить `much_parent`то полоска растянет само диалоговое окно пока не упрется в экран, если сделать `wrap_content` то она просто не займет ничего...

Я не уверен что обьяснил хорошо то что хочу так что спрашивайте если нужно что то добавить)

Спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый лучший способ проставить разделители:

- 1) Засунуть три кнопки в LinearLayout с горизонтальной ориентацией
- 2) LinearLayout задать свойства:

  ```
          android:divider="@drawable/my_divider"
          android:showDividers="middle"
  ```
- 3) Создать drawable ресурс @drawable/my_divider для разделителя:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
  </shape>
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Лучше посмотрите на material disign. Все что вам нужно будет, так это использование при создание диалога AlertDialog из appcompat v7. 
[Диалоги в стиле material design](https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html#)

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

AlertDialog.Builder builder =
   new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Dialog");
        builder.setMessage("r ....");
        builder.show();
```

А три кнопки можно сделать так

```
builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Button 1 Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    //...

} }); 

builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Button 2 Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    //...

}}); 

builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Button 3 Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    //...

}});
```